# How can I change the font padding of an Android button?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to remove the font padding from an Android button?

I've tried set includeFontPadding to false, but it has no effect.

How can i change the font padding of the button?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do. If you could explain your problem a little more, or provide some images to show what you want to achieve we maybe can help you.

Comment: Are You using standard button bg? If so, it contains paddings in where <Your platform path>\data\res\drawable-mdpi\btn_default_normal.9.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define a seperate drawable resource for the button something like this.
For example this is button_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#F5B800"
            android:endColor="#F5B800"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#ffcc00" />
        <corners
            android:radius="1dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_focused="true" >
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#F5B800"
            android:startColor="#F5B800"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#ffcc00" />
        <corners
            android:radius="1dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>        
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#ff9900"
            android:startColor="#ffcc00"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#ffcc00" />
        <corners
            android:radius="1dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Here you can arrange the padding as you want for the button.
And when you are declaring the button use this as the background.
Something like.

```
<Button android:id="@+id/sample_button"  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="@layout/button_layout"
        android:text="Sample Button" />
```

Comment: That's right. However, using of just simple drawables in selector are also possible. Also, button_layout.xml is not 'separate layout', but drawable resource.

Comment: You are right i used the wrong term there thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: How it will effect font padding?

Comment: I believe, me and Serdar Dogruyol think the issue is not in the font padding, but in padding included in the background of the button.

Comment: The padding is not from the text actually its comimg from the background  of the button resource here.So changing the padding in that resource will fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try using android:includeFontPadding. set it to false. also set the padding to 0.